# Searching for a number inside a tree

Tags: c, recursion, binary-tree, binary-search-tree

```
typedef struct Tree{
    int value;
    struct Tree* leftNode;
    struct Tree* rightNode;
}Tree;

Tree* Is_Existing_Number(Tree *root, int number, bool found) {

    if (!root || found)
        return root;

    if (root->value == number)
        found = true;

    else {
         Is_Existing_Number(root->leftNode, number, found);
         Is_Existing_Number(root->rightNode, number, found);
    }
}
```

I have a problem: I want to find if a tree has a specific number in it.  If it does, I want the function to return a pointer to it, so basically I want to go over the whole tree and check if that number exists in the tree.

Why doesn't this code work?

Comment: You're `else` clause needs to return the value from searching the left node if it is not null; otherwise, it needs to return the value from searching the right node.

Comment: btw.. what is the purpose of using BST if both branches are visited when looking for a value?

Comment: Your code is assuming that you have a binary tree, not a binary search tree.  If you have a binary search tree, then if the current node does not contain the value you're after, you know whether to look at the left subtree (because the value sought is smaller than the current node) or the right subtree (because the value sought is bigger).  This reduces the amount of searching needed.  You also need to return a value for the `if (root->value == number)` case (`return root;` — no need to set `found`).  Indeed, it is not clear that you need `found` at all.

Answer (score 1):

I assume that you use a Binary Search Tree (BST). Otherwise, it would be pointless to use the binary tree; an array/list would be mode suitable.

Values in a BST are ordered.  Thus all values stored in child's (i.e. leftNode) branch are larger than the value in the current node. The value in the other child's node (i.e. rightNode) are lesser than the value in the current node.

This lets it skip an entire child branch while looking for a value.

The code should look like this:

```
Tree *FindNumber(Tree* root, int value) {
  if (root == NULL) { // hit the leaf, value is absent
    return NULL;
  } else if (root->value == value) { // value found
    return root;
  } else if (root->value > value) { // try left node
    return FindNumber(root->leftNode, value);
  } else {
    return FindNumber(root->rightNode, value); // try right node
  }
}
```

You may need to swap the role of left and right node depending on how the tree is ordered.

If the function returns non-NULL then the value is present in the tree.

Comment: It is more usual to have smaller values in the left node and larger values in the right node, but that is a decision that can be made by the coder.  As long as everything is consistent, either definition works.